# iconv mac encodings list

Tags: mac-osx

I am using iconv installed with macports as well as the default iconv that comes with OSX. I want to use a certain encoding - sjis-win, which is not one of the supported encodings. On Linux, there are many more supported encodings.

So I am wondering if I need to reinstall iconv or if there is a way to enable more encodings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OS X 10.6's system-provided `iconv` does have the sjis-win encoding, but it's not aliased to that name.

On FreeBSD:

```
$ iconv -l | grep -i sjis-win
CP932 MS932 SHIFT_JIS-MS SJIS-MS SJIS-OPEN SJIS-WIN WINDOWS-31J WINDOWS-932 CSWINDOWS31J
```

Those are all the aliases of sjis-win.  We see that this encoding is also known as [code page 932](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_932).  So on OS X:

```
$ iconv -l | grep 932
CP932
```

The version of iconv included in OS X does have the sjis-win encoding, but you need to refer to it as cp932 because that's the only alias listed.